# Can't open or ping my ISP's authentication page only from my linux machine

Tags: networking, internet, ping

**SCENARIO**

I just got a new internet connection. It's a fiber optic connection connected to a modem to which my linux computer is connected to through ethernet cable. To get internet access I have to connect the ethernet cable to the machine and go to x.xxx.xxx.xxx to login (Authentication by my ISP I guess)

**PROBLEM**

The above said authentication address(x.xxx.xxx.xxx) won't open. And the ping to 8.8.8.8 and the above said authentication page (x.xxx.xxx.xxx) returns `connect: Network is unreachable`. Initially I felt that my ethernet cable was not getting detected but that's not the case.

Without cable connected

```
ip link show up
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether <<my mac addr>> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether <<my wifi mac addr>> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

With cable connected

```
ip link show up
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:f9:dd:5a:2c:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:53:2e:0a:af:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**I FACE ABSOLUTELY NO SUCH PROBLEM WHEN I TRY IT THROUGH MY WINDOWS AND MAC COMPUTERS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with DHCP
Added the following code to `/etc/network/interfaces` and it started to work after some time.

```
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Basically no ip address(ipv4. ipv6 was present as its just a modification of the mac address and not assigned by the ISP) was getting assigned to me and the above addition fixed the problem.